# C Compiler expects identifier before function

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

Ive been trying to write a minesweeper function in c that expands an area of blocks whenever it hits a blank space, yet I keep getting the error `...\Desktop\Test\main.c|38|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'int'` whenever I try to build, although the function seems perfectly fine to me. My code is here:

```
#include <windows.h> /* for HANDLE type, and console functions */
#include <stdio.h> /* standard input/output */
#include <stdlib.h> /* included for rand */

#define WIDTH 30
#define HEIGHT 30
#define BOMBS 90

HANDLE wHnd; /* write (output) handle */
HANDLE rHnd; /* read (input handle */

void SetGrid(int grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    int bomb[2] = { abs(rand() % WIDTH-1) + 1,
                   abs(rand() % HEIGHT-1) + 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < BOMBS; i++)
    {
        while (grid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] < -1 || bomb[0] == 0 || bomb[1] == 0 || bomb[0] >= WIDTH-1 || bomb[1] >= HEIGHT-1)
        {
            bomb[0] = abs(rand() % WIDTH-1) + 1;
            bomb[1] = abs(rand() % HEIGHT-1) + 1;
        }

        grid[bomb[0]][bomb[1]] = -9;

        grid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1]    ]++;
        grid[bomb[0]    ][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] + 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0]    ][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] + 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1] - 1]++;
        grid[bomb[0] - 1][bomb[1]    ]++;
    }
}

void ExpandGrid(int fullGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] int blankPos[2])
{
    int neighbors[8][2] = {{0,1}, {1,0}, {1,1},
                          {0,-1},        {-1,0},
                          {-1,-1},{-1,1},{1,-1}};
    int curTile[2];

    for(int blck = 0; blck < 8; ++blck)
    {
        curTile[0] = blankPos[0]+neighbors[blck][0];
        curTile[1] = blankPos[1]+neighbors[blck][1];

        if(fullGrid[curTile[0], curTile[1]] == 0)
        {
            knownGrid[curTile[0], curTile[1]] == 1;
            ExpandGrid(fullGrid, knownGrid, curTile);
        }
        else if(fullGrid[curTile[0], curTile[1]] > 0) {knownGrid[curTile[0], curTile[1]] == 1};
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* there will be two grids, a known grid and a full grid.
       for the full grid, a zero at a position [x][y] will indicate a blank space.
       a positive will be the tiles number, and a negative will be a bomb.

       for the known grid, a zero at space [x][y] will indicate an unknown block.
       while a 1 will indicate it is uncovered.
    */

    srand(time(0));

    SMALL_RECT windowSize = { 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 };

    //COORD bufferSize = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };

    COORD characterBufferSize = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    COORD characterPosition = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT consoleWriteArea = { 0, 0, WIDTH - 1, HEIGHT - 1 };

    CHAR_INFO consoleBuffer[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTitle("Minesweeper!");

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, TRUE, &windowSize);
    //SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(wHnd, bufferSize);

    int startGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = { 0 };
    SetGrid(startGrid);

    for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y)
        {
            if (startGrid[x][y] > 0)
            {
                consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = '0' + startGrid[x][y];
                consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
            }
            else
            {
                consoleBuffer[x][y].Char.AsciiChar = 'o';
                consoleBuffer[x][y].Attributes = (startGrid[x][y] < 0 ? FOREGROUND_RED : FOREGROUND_BLUE) | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY;
            }
        }
    }

    WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, consoleBuffer, characterBufferSize, characterPosition, &consoleWriteArea);

    getchar();
}
```

if I'm correct, this error usually only appears when you forget to put an ending to your previous line of code, but here I don't think that's the case. Does this have to do with the fact that the function is recursive, or is it a quirk of the compiler? I'm pretty new to c, as you may tell.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Note: `knownGrid[curTile[0], curTile[1]] == 1;` doesn't do anything. You mean `=`? You make that error twice.

Comment: `fullGrid[curTile[0], curTile[1]]` This is not how 2 dimensions of an array are addressed. You are using a coma operator which is very likely not what you want. This should be `fullGrid[curTile[0]][curTile[1]]`. Same for `knownGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header of the function definition of `ExpandGrid()`:

```
void ExpandGrid(int fullGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT] int blankPos[2])
                                                                         |
                                                                        here
```

a comma (`,`) is missing before the definition of the last parameter `blankPos`.

That's what the error message is for.

It should be:

```
void ExpandGrid(int fullGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int knownGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT], int blankPos[2])
```